# Understanding how to insert one GIT repo into another

Tags: git, bitbucket

Im hoping somebody may be able to explain (in as simple plain English as possible!) and point me in the right direction when it comes to combining GIT repos.  I know this is question that is asked often, but I am getting totally lost with this problem.

I have one GIT repo (that is both local and remote - the remote version being on Bitbucket) lets call it the Master, which uses the four common Gitflow branches.  Now I have two other repos, one handling common files, that is just being worked on by me (call this Repo A) and another which is being worked on and updated by a colleague (Repo B). Repo A is hosted on Bitbucket, while B is on Github.

All three Repo have slightly different file structures.  Lets say the original has the following folder structure:

```
\app\controller
\app\assets
\app\models
\app\views
```

Now I need to get the content of Repo B and add it to the existing content in \app\models, in such a way that no existing files in \app\models are replaced, and at that Repo B still exists separately, and any future updates to it can be pulled into my Master Repo easily.  Repo B also has the controller and views folders but these are empty.

The second repo (A) needs to pulled into \app\views\repoA folder which does not currently exist in the master.  Again Repo A still needs to exist separately, as it is being worked on independently, so I will need to pull the changes down.  At the moment the folder structure in Repo A is simple \htmlfiles within which are the files that need to end up in \app\views\repoA

In both cases, to keep the audit trial and documentation correct, I ideally need to keep the full comment and commit history intact if possible.  With both Repos, I may need to undertake amends in the Master Repo and push them back to the remote original Repos as well.

Now i gather there are options to do with forking and subtree, but I'm getting totally lost with how these work, and am rapidly getting to a point I don't want to get to where i'll just pull the ZIP file down and manually update things!

Can anyone help in pointing me in the right direction, or explaining in simple terms the best way of doing something? Im assuming its possible to do all of this with GIT and that I'm not asking too much!

I want to understand how the different GIT options work and what they do, so that I will be able to use it fully in the future!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to keep the history of the changes in Repo B?

Comment: For that repo it wouldn't be a requirement, more of an if possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging codebases that have diverged considerably can be a lot of work.

Because your two repo's were built in isolation, differ in structure/layout and its not necessarily essential that you keep the history of repo B, I would recommend the following:

1. Get Repo A into a sensible state.
2. Create a feature branch from repo A
3. Hand-merge the code from Repo B into the feature branch's codebase, committing changes one at a time
4. Once merged, build and test that everything is to your liking
5. Checkout your master branch
6. Merge/squash your feature branch into master

NEXT TIME around: I recommend having all team members work on their own branches/forks, but RI/FI regularly with the main repo - at least every 2-3 days, more frequently if code changes are rapid. Aim for small changes merged frequently rather than large divergent changes spanning multiple days (or longer).

Comment: Thanks for that. I came into this project after it had started, but are you saying that if Repo A and B had been forked from the master, they would have been easier to update back to the master?

Comment: Generally speaking, if forked from a master and kept in sync with master over time, projects tend not to diverge too far in terms of structure etc. If you've two separate repo's that were created separately and rarely synchronized, then, yes, there's a high likelihood that they'll diverge more quickly.

Comment: Glad to have been of help :)